# How to use nested If statements in SQL trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2005

I'm trying to learn SQL triggers to automatically handle events in my database but I'm having some problems with execution.

If I run the following code:

```
declare @userid numeric(18,0);
declare @username nvarchar(max);
set @userid = 400
execute GetUserNameFromID @userid,@username output
select @username
```

which calls the following stored procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE GetUserNameFromID 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @UserID numeric(18,0),
    @UserName nvarchar(MAX) OUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT @UserName = u.name from Users u where ID=@UserID
END
GO
```

I get a nice result 'sometestuser'

But when calling it from my trigger it fails to return a value from the stored procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER Trigger [dbo].[CheckIfUserHasNoItemsLeft] on [dbo].[Items] for update
As

Begin
set nocount on 

declare @inactive_user nvarchar(50);
declare @userid numeric(18,0);
declare @username nvarchar(MAX);

if ( select Count(*) from inserted ) > 1 RaIsError( 'CheckIfIserHasNoItemsLeft: No more than one row may be processed.', 25, 42 ) with log

if update(InactiveUser)
    set @inactive_user = (select InactiveUser from inserted)
    if @inactive_user is not null
        set @userid = (select CID from inserted)
        execute GetuserNameFromID @userid,@username output
        if @username is not null        
            insert into tasks (Task) values ('The last item for ' + @username + ' has been marked inactive, check if this user should now be also marked inactive.')
End
```

InactiveUser is the name of the app user who has marked this item inactive, it is what I am using as a check to see if the item has been set inactive rather than create an additional boolean column just for this purpose.

I'm sure it's something simple but information on If...Then statements for SQL seems to be limited and a lot of answers suggest using Case but the query editor gives me errors about incorrect syntax no matter which way I try to do it that way.

As I'm learning I'm more than happy for someone to show me a completely new way of handling this if what I've done is wrong or bad design.  I'm hoping to create a set of triggers that will add items to the tasks table for administrators to check when user accounts appear to be stale and other maintenance checks etc.

I am using SQL server 2005.

Thank you.

Edit: Changed 'value <> null' to 'value is not null'
Edit2: Added HABO's suggestion to throw an error if more than one row is detected.

Comment: There are a couple of issues here. First is your trigger is an update and the procedure does not update the Items table so it isn't going to fire the trigger. Your trigger itself has a MAJOR fundamental issue, it assumes that there will only ever be one row in inserted. You need to write set based logic in your triggers as they fire once per operation, not once per row.

Comment: I forgot to mention that, yes.  My application will only ever mark one item inactive in a single operation so I did it this way to keep it simple until I'd got it working and then look at how to handle multiple rows so I know how to do it properly.
The trigger is meant to fire on an operation such as 
    'update Items set InactiveUser = someuser where ID = ItemID'

Comment: Oh boy...your trigger has more issues than using scalar variables. You have <> NULL all over it. That will never evaluate to true no matter what. You need to use IS NULL

Comment: But your application is NOT the only thing that can update this table. And just because it is done that way today does NOT mean it can't change in the future. It is a problem so major that is literally closed down an entire business that a consultant friend of mine worked with. They had triggers all over the place like that and it was too much effort and time to fix them all so they just closed the doors.

Comment: If you are absolutely certain there will never be more than one row then _please_ add a check for the number of rows and use `RaIsError` or `Throw` to explicitly inform those who come along later that they have attempted to execute an unacceptable statement. (`if ( select Count(*) from inserted ) > 1 RaIsError( 'FooTable_Insert: No more than one row may be processed.', 25, 42 ) with log`)

Comment: @SeanLange I think you mean use IS NOT NULL.

Comment: I agree with you, I just wanted to get my head around triggers and stored procedures by getting something relatively simple working, as soon as I get this trigger to fire and do what I want I'll be reading up on and implementing something to handle any number of rows before I create the rest of the triggers I need.

So I should change my code to read 'if (at)inactive_user is not null' ?

Comment: Also, your conditions are not nested. every if statement only effect the next row after it. if you wish to effect code blocks and not just single rows, you need to specify them with `begin....end`. so the basic structure is `if <condition> begin <statements> end`.

Comment: @Zohar so in my example I have a nested if, can I do the following?
if <condition> begin <statements> if <condition> begin <more statements> end end

Comment: @LostRob: paraphrasing barak obama: yes, you can.

Comment: Thanks to everyone here! I've learnt a lot of new things as well as getting a solution to my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about we take a whole new approach to this. Processes like this are exactly why the inline table valued functions were created.

Let's start by converting your stored procedure to an inline table valued function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetUserNameFromID 
(
    @UserID numeric(18,0)
) RETURNS TABLE 
AS RETURN

    SELECT u.name 
    from Users u 
    where ID = @UserID
GO
```

That is a LOT simpler and cleaner than that stored procedure with an output variable.

Here is where it really starts to make a difference. Here is what you could do with that trigger using the newly created iTVF.

```
ALTER Trigger [dbo].[CheckIfUserHasNoItemsLeft] on [dbo].[Items] for update
As Begin

set nocount on 

if update(InactiveUser)
    insert into tasks (Task) 
    select 'The last item for ' + u.name + ' has been marked inactive, check if this user should now be also marked inactive.'
    from inserted i
    cross apply dbo.GetUserNameFromID(i.CID) u
end
```

This is super simple AND it is fully set based so if you update 1 or 1,000 rows it will work correctly.

Comment: This looks perfect but when I try to trigger it with " update Users set InactiveUser = 'someuser' where ItemID = 'someID' " a row doesn't get added to Tasks, any ideas what I've missed?

Comment: Because the trigger is on the Items table. I wondered about that but that is what you had posted. I also wanted to ask you, do you really have your UserName as varchar(max)??? Seems a more reasonable size would be sufficient. I doubt you need to allow user names of up to 2GB of characters. :)

Comment: I meant 'Items', I'm not sure why I typed 'Users' but it wasn't working.  I deleted everything and started fresh with your examples and now it's working so thank you very much!  Yes, the UserName is set to varchar(MAX) and now you mention it I can't think why, probably a newbie mistake I made when I started writing this that I've just got used to seeing, I'll reduce it down to something a bit more sensible! :)